# Can't access Kibana remotely

Tags: windows, elasticsearch, centos, kibana, remote-access

I have installed Elasticsearch and kibana in the same Centos server. When running netstat -nlp | grep :5601 I get the below result:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5601            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      27244/node
```

But I still can't access kibana remotely from my windows client, when I try to access kibana from my windows client in browser using "http://my_server_ip:5601", I get something like this:

```
This page cannot be accessed
...(omitted)
ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

However, I can access ES from my windows client in browser using "http://my_server_ip:9200":

```
{
  "name" : "VM-251-156-centos",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "FsL8YI1mQAGqx3R0kffxbw",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.10.2",
    "build_flavor" : "oss",
    "build_type" : "rpm",
    "build_hash" : "747e1cc71def077253878a59143c1f785afa92b9",
    "build_date" : "2021-01-13T00:42:12.435326Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.7.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

I have searched all day long, almost all the answers suggested to edit the kibana.yml, changing server.host to 0.0.0.0, but they don't work in my case.

My kibana.yml is like this (only list uncommented lines):

```
server.port: 5601 
server.host: "0.0.0.0" 
server.name: "http://kibana.example.com" 
elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://my_server_ip:9200"]
```

And I have checked the firewall in Centos server using the command "firewall-cmd --state":

```
not running
```

And I have also confirmed that kibana is really running in the Centos server using "sudo systemctl status kibana":

```
● kibana.service - Kibana
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/kibana.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2022-01-26 13:57:44 CST; 19h ago
 Main PID: 27244 (node)
    Tasks: 11
   Memory: 80.6M
   CGroup: /system.slice/kibana.service
           └─27244 /usr/share/kibana/bin/../node/bin/node /usr/share/kibana/bin/../src/cli/dist
```

Any suggesstions is appreciated.

Comment: Comment out the `server.name`. I don't think you need that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by changing "server.port: 5601" to "server.port: 5602" in the kibana.yml.

It turns out that the problem was caused by the 5601 port in the centos server was blocked by the server provider for security concerns.

Comment: But I still don't know how to check whether a port is blocked or not by my self. Who can help to give a answer?
PS: In this case, I was told the 5601 port was blocked  by the  server  administrator.